# php - DateInterval over midnight issue

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval, timeslots

I want to generate time slots with `DateInterval` and i have an issue when i select end period over midnight(00:00).

Everything generates if my end period is till "23:59".

Here is my code with input variables:

```
$duration = 30; // duration interval<br>
$start    = '22:00'; // start period<br>
$end      = '02:00'; // end period<br>

function generateTimeSlots($duration, $start, $end) {
    $start         = new DateTime($start);
    $end           = new DateTime($end);
    $interval      = new DateInterval("PT" . $duration . "M");
    $periods = array(); 

    for ($intStart = $start; $intStart < $end; $intStart->add($interval)) {
        $endPeriod = clone $intStart;
        $endPeriod->add($interval); 
        if ($endPeriod > $end) {
            $endPeriod = $end;
        }
        $periods[] = $intStart->format('H:i A');
    }

    return $periods;
}


$duration = 30;
$start    = '22:00'; // 10:00 PM
$end      = '02:00'; // 02:00 AM

print_r( generateTimeSlots($duration, $start, $end) );
```

Expected output:
22:00 PM
22:30 PM
23:00 PM
23:30 PM
00:00 PM
00:30 PM
01:00 PM
01:30 PM
02:00 PM

Is not generating any time slots if my end period is over `23:59`.

Anyone knows what should be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to also include the information about the day in the `$start` and `$end` parameters. If they are not mentionned, `DateTime` will automatically select the current day, which in your example means that your start date is `2018-01-19 22:00:00` and your end date is `2018-01-19 02:00:00`. Since your end date is *after* your end date, your `for` loop is simply never iterated.

---

To get around this you can either specify the entire date and time, or to use PHP's native date recognition. I personally lean towards using complete dates as I find it tends to make the code more robust by not having to interpret human readable strings.

```
// using complete dates
$startDateTime = new DateTime('2018-01-19 22:00:00');
$endDateTime = new DateTime('2018-01-20 02:00:00');

// using human readable strings    
$startDateTime = new DateTime('today 22pm');
$endDateTime = new DateTime('tomorrow 2am');
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and use strtotime() function. This way you are only dealing with one integer.  Then on your view side you can covert it back to whatever you need.

```
function generateTimeSlots($duration, $start, $end) {

    $periods = array(); 

    for ($intStart = $start; $intStart <= $end; $intStart += $duration) {
        // $endPeriod = clone $intStart;
        // $endPeriod = $end; 
        // if ($endPeriod > $end) {
        //     $endPeriod = $end;
        // }
        $periods[] = date('H:i A', $intStart);
    }

    return $periods;
}


$duration = 1800; #1800 seconds (30 minutes)
$start    = strtotime('Today 22:00'); // 10:00 PM Today
$end      = strtotime('Tomorrow 02:00'); // 02:00 AM Tomorrow

print_r( generateTimeSlots($duration, $start, $end) );
```